# Html.RenderAction is not available after including Microsoft.Web.Mvc dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We want to use Html.RenderAction in our MVC1.0 project. I have downloaded the Futures Microsoft.Web.Mvc dll from codeplex, copied it to the bin folder in our project, and added a reference to it.

However, when I try to use it in one of our views, Html.RenderAction is still not available.

It might be just a silly detail I'm missing, but I have no idea what else I have to do :(

P.S. I checked, and I can actually write "Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewExtensions.RenderAction" and Visual Studio autocompletes the code just fine, so it seems the dll is correctly included in the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add it to the "namespaces" tag in web.config.

```
 <system.web>
      <pages>
         <namespaces>
           <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
         </namespaces>
      </pages>
   </system.web>
```

Comment: That was it! So easy, yet every page I found about Futures omitted this step(!)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

RenderAction is part of the [MvcFutures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471) project.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You might need to modify your web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```